# Why does simple form not show validation error messages in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

The :new view when redirected if validations are not matched and where I'd like to see the error messages:

```
<%= simple_form_for ([ @recipe, @recipe.comments.build]), class:"comment-form" do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>
<%= f.object.errors.full_messages.join(", ") if f.object.errors.any? %>
<%= f.input :name, label: false, placeholder: "Your name", input_html: { value: @comment.name } %>
<%= f.input :comment, label: false, placeholder: "Tell us about your experience", input_html: { value: @comment.comment } %>
<%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn-comment-submit" %>
<% end %>
```

This is my controller:

```
  def new
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:recipe_id])
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comment = @recipe.comments.build
  end

  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:recipe_id])
    @comment.recipe = @recipe
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to recipe_path(@recipe)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Comment: `@recipe.comments.build` is not `@comment`. Change that part to `@comment` and add `@comment = @recipe.comments.build` to the new action in the controller. Honestly I have no idea how this doesn't error out in the first place can you post your new action too?

Comment: @engineersmnky it won't error out since `@recipe` is most likely set wherever the form is rendered. If I had to venture a guess based on the names this form is "embedded" on the recipies show or index view and may not have a separate new action. This is a textbook "I'm embedding a form on another page" problem.

Comment: @max I guess I could have been a bit more explanatory. I am more interested in how `@comment` is set in `new` since it isn't used in the form builder but is used in the form itself as `@comment.name` and `@comment.value` which would most certainly error.

Comment: @engineersmnky ah missed that as most people do when you have 100+ character lines. Its also completely unessicary busywork.

Comment: @max my human compiler works overtime. I do more code review than actual coding these days so these are the things that catch my eye ( also why I hate partial examples on SO even when the parts that are missing aren't pertinent to the issue at hand)

Comment: Thank you @max and @engineersmnky! I was able to fix it. I have a show view with a simple form and when the input is not valid its getting redirected to the new view where I pass the pre-filled inputs and display the error messages.

Comment: Sounds like you might want  to use a partial instead of repeating the code. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not binding the `@comment` instance you have created in your controller to the form. Instead `@recipe.comments.build` always creates a new instance of Comment.

You can set the model with a conditional:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@recipe, @comment || @recipe.comments.build]) do |form| %> 
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.object.errors.full_messages.join(", ") if f.object.errors.any? %>
  <%= f.input :name, label: false, placeholder: "Your name" %>
  <%= f.input :comment, label: false, placeholder: "Tell us about your experience" %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn-comment-submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Note that you don't need to set the values for the inputs. The form builder will do that for you. Thats kind of the whole point of it.

Or you can preferably ensure that you're setting `@comment` in the controller to keep the view as simple as possible:

```
class RecipiesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_recipe
  # ...
  def show
    @comment = @recipe.comments.new
  end

  # ...
end
```

```
<%= simple_form_for([@recipe, @comment]) do |form| %>
   # ...
<% end %>
```

And you can clean up your create action and just create the comment off the recipe:

```
def create
  @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:recipe_id])
  @comment = @recipe.comments.new(comment_params)
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to @recipe
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: @engineersmnky `build` is just an alias for `new` since Rails 3 or something like that. I generally prefer `.new` as it its pretty straight forward that its just creating a new instance.  And yes new sets the id when you build off an association. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/65979c693bbf212736acc41bb200f04032cf9683/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L73

Comment: I stand corrected although I think I'd still prefer the opposite as I like the distinction and it falls more in line with a singular resource (`has_one`) builder e.g. `@user.build_profile` where there is no corresponding `record.new_association_name`